# How do I list fields in object inside array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I'm working with the structure below for a multilanguage site. For this I'll be doing a tool to add/edit the needed words in the different languages that'll be available.

What I want to do is use a MongoDB (or Mongoose) query on my NodeJS/Express backend to get the keys for a specific language-

```
{
    "languages": [
        {
            "_id": "5d4ee75c1c9d4400007e9bd8",
            "code": "en",
            "texts": [
                {
                    "key": "language",
                    "word": "English"
                },
                {
                    "key": "title",
                    "word": "Colorblindness"
                },
                {
                    "key": "login",
                    "word": "Login"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d4ee8631c9d4400007e9bd9",
            "code": "es",
            "texts": [
                {
                    "key": "language",
                    "word": "Español"
                },
                {
                    "key": "title",
                    "word": "Daltonismo"
                },
                {
                    "key": "account",
                    "word": "Cuenta"
                },
                {
                    "key": "exit",
                    "word": "Salir"
                }
            ]
        },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

For example, if I query on "en" (English language), I'd expect the result to be something like

```
["language", "title", "login"]
```

, but if I query on "es" (Spanish language), the result should be

```
["language", "title", "account", "exit"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Schema.findOne({code: "en"},(err,res)=>{
if (res) console.log(res.texts);
});
```

It's mongoose, it won't work with it's current but you need to edit it depending on your code starting by schema name.

Assuming every code has it's own fields, you should change "en" to "es".

Answer (score 0):

For your query, assuming ***languages.code*** has unique values :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
  {$match:{'languages.code': "es"}},
  {$unwind:'$languages'},
  {$match:{'languages.code': "es"}},
  {$project:{keys:'$languages.texts.key'}}
])
```

Assuming your collection is a large dataset then adding `$match` as first stage would filter documents where at-least one element of **languages.code** has value 'es'.